# Terminal echo issue

Tags: command-line

I've been using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS for a while, am quite new, using the terminal, made a script to open a project of mine containing multiple files with gedit - after execution of the respective script:

```
gedit [filename1] [filename2] ...
```

The terminal executes it successfully, gedit opens passed files and terminal is ready for another line. Well, today I came across a strange issue - after the execution of the above mentioned script, gedit initiates successfully, but **terminal denies execution of commands and echoes all keyboard events**,  even specific <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>...</kbd> functions - all until gedit is closed.

I can't figure what caused this as my recent activity was focused around a C project, not regarding the terminal in any way. I recall being able to execute another line after initiating e.g. open gedit and compile a project within a single tab and session of a terminal window. Any help would be appreciated!
Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to launch gedit in the back ground by appending `&` to the command that starts gedit. e.g. `gedit file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt &`